# CSS media query not working when resizing browser

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to use a media query to make a div responsive on a site (using IE11).

This is my CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) { // Tried with "only screen" also

  .divStyle {
      background-image:none;
      background-color:red;
      background-position:right;
      color:#fff!important;
      height:140px;
      position:relative;
      top:-6px;

    }

}

.divStyle {
  background-image:url('/images/image.jpg');
  background-position:right;
  color:#fff!important;
  padding:20px;
  height:190px;
  position:relative;
  top:-6px;

}
```

I've also added the metatag in the Head section.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

But it still doesn't respond when I'm resizing the window.

Comment: You must to include the mediaqueries after the normal styles. In your code, the mediaquery is first and then overrides with the same class. Just turn reverse the code and it works

Comment: Your media queries are working properly. I tested this on Chrome and IE11

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude, not necessarily

Comment: Is a good practice. Is better take care of overriding styles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case the rule without the media query follows after the one with the media query. So it overwrites the rule.

Change their order to this.

```
.divStyle {
  background-image:url('/images/image.jpg');
  background-position:right;
  color:#fff!important;
  padding:20px;
  height:190px;
  position:relative;
  top:-6px;

} 

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) { 
  .divStyle {
      background-image:none;
      background-color:red;
      background-position:right;
      color:#fff!important;
      height:140px;
      position:relative;
      top:-6px;
    }
}
```

Comment: so I realized that there is syntax to be considered `@media only` vs `@media` and `max-device-wdith` vs `max-width` - Tells me that we can be very specific as to what screen we want our media queries to take effect on.